# Usage of prefix or postfix increment (or decrement)

Tags: c++, operators

I've found this code is as an example of the usage of the comma-operator in a C++ book (C++ Primer, 5th Edition):

```
vector<int>::size_type cnt = ivec.size();
// assign values from size...1 to the elements in ivec
for(vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix != ivec.size(); ++ix, --cnt)
    ivec[ix] = cnt;
```

I don't think that this is an appropriate example, because the [order of evalation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and side-effects don't matter here. The comma-operator just allows for separating the increment and decrement expressions, which is a common usage of the comma operator, but not the intention of this section in the book. A better [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) is shown at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) (please scroll down to the headline **Built-in comma operator**).

What is really on my mind is the following exercise:

> **Exercise 4.31** The program in this section used the prefix increment and decrement operators. Explain why we used prefix and not
>   postfix. What changes would have to be made to use the postfix
>   versions? Rewrite the program using the postfix operators.

There is no special reason to prefer the prefix over the postfix operators in this case. The evaluation order doesn't matter. The manipulation of objects with `simple` type like `vector<int>::size_type` shouldn't benefit from the usage of prefix over postfix in practice, so it's just a known convention to prefer prefix over postfix, in case the performance matters.

To give you the full context, here the section from the book:

> **4.10 Comma Operator**
>   The **comma operator** takes two operands, which it evaluates from left to right. Like the logical *AND* and
>   logical *OR* and the conditional operator, the comma operator
>   guarantees the order in which its operands are evaluated.
>
> The left-hand expression is evaluated and its result is discareded.
>   The result of a comma expressions is the value of its right-hand
>   expression. The result is an lvalue if the right-hand operand is an
>   lvalue. One common use for the comma operator is in a for loop:
>
> ```
> vector<int>::size_type cnt = ivec.size();  
> // assign values from size...1 to the elements in ivec  
> for(vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix != ivec.size(); ++ix, --cnt)  
>     ivec[ix] = cnt;
> ```
>
> This loop increments *ix* and decrements *cnt* in the expression in
>   the for header. Both *ix* and *cnt* are changed on each trip through
>   the loop. As long as the test of *ix* succeeds, we reset the
>   <s>[next](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321714114/errata/9780321714114_errata_10-31-12.html)</s> current element to the current value of *cnt*.

Am I right? Or do I just not get the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that switching from prefix to postfix would make no difference in this example.

Comment: Thanks for affirmation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right about using prefix or postfix increment operator doesn't matter in this example, but *C++ Primer* also says that only use postfix version when really necessary as a **best practice**, I'm quoting the book from *§4.5. Increment and Decrement Operators*

> #### Advice: Use Postfix Operators only When Necessary
>
> Readers from a C background might be surprised that we use the prefix increment in the programs we've written. The reason is simple: The prefix version avoids unnecessary work. It increments the value and returns the incremented version.The postfix operator must store the original value so that it can return the unincremented value as its result. If we don’t need the unincremented value, there’s no need for the extra work done by the postfix operator.
>
> For `int`s and pointers, the compiler can optimize away this extra work. For more complicated iterator types, this extra work potentially might be more costly. By habitually using the prefix versions, we do not have to worry about whether the performance difference matters. Moreover—and perhaps more importantly—we can express the intent of our programs more directly.

Comment: Would a decent compiler really generate different code when the resulting value of the increment expression is not used?

Comment: @WiSaGaN Perhaps most compilers are smart enough that there's no performance different between the two. But like the second part of the quote says, keeping it as a habit has no harm. And since the question is about a C++ Primer exercise, this can at least explain what the authors think on this subject.

Comment: Yep! Applying good habits and sane defaults is always a good idea. In the long term, this little thinkgs keep the code readable (semantic behind prefix and postfix) and avoid nasty pitfalls (badly optimizing compilers, complicated types and so on).

Comment: @WiSaGaN: If the pre- and post-increment operators are defined in a different compilation module, the compiler can't know _anything_ about what they do. So it is not allowed to replace one with the other.